# python objects interference

Tags: java, python, object, oop

below java code will print two lists with **A** and **B** values.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {

    private String value;
    private ArrayList<String> ss = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyClass(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void initialize(){
        this.arrayList.add(this.value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass a = new MyClass("A");
        a.initialize();
        System.out.println(a.ss);

        MyClass b = new MyClass("B");
        b.initialize();
        System.out.println(b.ss);
    }
}
```

output as expected:

```
[A]
[B]
```

so, the python solution should return same results but it doesn't work.

```
class MyClass:
    ss = []
    value = None

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def initialize(self):
        self.ss.append(self.value)


a = MyClass("A")
a.initialize()
print(a.ss)

b = MyClass("B")
b.initialize()
print(b.ss)
```

output:

```
['A']
['A', 'B']
```

I don't know why object **a** infers on object **b**. Looks like for object **b** the **ss** variable is already filled with values from object **a**. How can I solve this problem? I am learning python but this behavior doesn't exist in java.

Comment: Please think on this daily: java is not python. Every language is different from every other language, and trying to think of them in the same way is just another way to hurt your brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, we write

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.ss = []
        self.value = value

    def initialize(self):
        self.ss.append(self.value)


a = MyClass("A")
a.initialize()
print(a.ss)
# ['A']    

b = MyClass("B")
b.initialize()
print(b.ss)
# ['B']
```

The way you had defined it, `ss` was treated as a static variable.

Generally speaking you refer to static variables in python by writing `MyClass.ss` instead of `self.ss`. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible-in-python):

> Variables declared inside the class definition, but not inside a
> method are class or static variables

Which was your problem.